# Can I download all Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, download

I want to download all my photographs from Google Photos. I found out that I can download 500 files in one zip file. I mark the first photo, scroll down 500 photos, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and mark the last photo. This way I can download 500 photos.

I found out that I can select all photos of a day by pressing on the checkmark next to the day.

[image: Select all photos of a day with one click]

Is there a way to download all photos?

Answer (score 4):

With additional research I found out, that I can use a service called [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout?pli=1) to have a big zip file generated (40 GB in my case) that can be downloaded.

Comment: My original task was to download all photos. This is done with Takeout.

Comment: can you download the original resolution of your media?

Comment: No, because I chose in [Settings](https://photos.google.com/settings) **High quality**. **Original quality** would be original resolution, see [Choose the upload size of your photos and videos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en).